# Edgehtml COM API

Tags: winapi, mfc, microsoft-edge, mshtml

According to the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdgeHTML) page about EdgeHTML they are providing a COM API to us. I want to use it in my c++ application like the old IE web browser control.

[image: From wiki]

I've been searching everywhere for tlb, clsid, documentation etc but found nothing. Does anyone know where I can find more information about the COM API?

Comment: The wiki section you are quoting does not have a reference so it might not be factual information.

Comment: Doesn't look like it has been formally released yet. The current status can be seen in Microsoft Edge' [Dev Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/whats-new).

Comment: It's probably not yet available. I found [this feature request](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/15274089-provide-component-object-model-access-to-edgehtml) for the function you asked.

Comment: I came across my old question today and I can answer this myself now:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/